# error: Invalid JSON RPC response: "" when trying to transfer testnet token

Tags: web3js, nodejs, alchemy

I am trying to transfer testnet tokens using Node.js, Web3.js, Ethers, and Alchemy but I am receiving `Invalid JSON RPC response: ""` whenever I deploy my code to [Railway](https://railway.app). Is this an issue of Railway or with my code? If with my code then what's the issue?

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import Web3 from 'web3';

import constants from '../data/constants';
import {
  chainId,
  txUrl,
  apiKeys,
  httpsUrls,
  amount,
  ethersSupportedNetworkNames,
} from '../data/networks';

dotenv.config();

const privateKey = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey as string);

const token = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const XHR = require('xhr2-cookies').XMLHttpRequest;
  XHR.prototype._onHttpRequestError = function (
    request: { abort: () => void },
    error: any
  ) {
    if (this._request !== request) {
      return;
    }

    console.log(error, 'request');
    this._setError();
    request.abort();
    this._setReadyState(XHR.DONE);
    this._dispatchProgress('error');
    this._dispatchProgress('loadend');
  };

  const address = wallet.address;

  const networkApiKey = apiKeys.get(String(req.query.network));
  const networkHttpsUrl = httpsUrls.get(String(req.query.network));

  var web3 = new Web3(
    new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(networkHttpsUrl as string)
  );

  const httpsProvider = new ethers.providers.AlchemyProvider(
    ethersSupportedNetworkNames.get(req.query.network as string),
    networkApiKey
  );

  let nonce = await httpsProvider.getTransactionCount(address, 'latest');

  let feeData = await httpsProvider.getFeeData();

  const balance = web3.utils.fromWei(
    await web3.eth.getBalance(constants['fromAddress']),
    'ether'
  );

  if (web3.utils.isAddress(String(req.query.address!)) === false) {
    res.json({
      error: 'Invalid receiver address',
      invalidAddress: true,
    });
  } else {
    if (balance < amount?.get(req.query.network as string)!) {
      res.json({
        error: 'Insufficient funds',
        insufficientFunds: true,
      });
    } else {
      const tx = {
        type: 2,
        nonce: nonce,
        to: req.query.address,
        maxPriorityFeePerGas: feeData['maxPriorityFeePerGas'],
        maxFeePerGas: feeData['maxFeePerGas'],
        value: ethers.utils.parseEther(
          amount.get(req.query.network as string) as string
        ),
        gasLimit: 30000,
        chainId: chainId.get(String(req.query.network)),
      };

      const signedTx = await wallet.signTransaction(tx as any);

      const txHash = ethers.utils.keccak256(signedTx);
      console.log('Precomputed txHash:', txHash);
      httpsProvider.sendTransaction(signedTx).then(console.log);

      res.json({
        txLink: `${txUrl.get(String(req.query.network))}/${txHash}`,
      });
    }
  }
};

export default token;
```

I tried the solution by the Infura community https://community.infura.io/t/invalid-json-rpc-response-error/1281 but still, it doesn't solve my issue.

Here is the entire error:
[image: the entire error]

The code of other files which I have imported into the main file:

`data/constants.ts`

```
const constants = {
  fromAddress: '0x894b6579524c61b56B3aB5624740464EaDF5237E',
};

export default constants;
```

`data/networks.ts`

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

const chainId = new Map([
  ['mumbai', 80001],
  ['rinkeby', 4],
]);

const txUrl = new Map([
  ['mumbai', 'https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx'],
  ['rinkeby', 'https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx'],
]);

const apiKeys = new Map([
  ['mumbai', process.env.ALCHEMY_API_KEY_MUMBAI],
  ['rinkeby', process.env.ALCHEMY_API_KEY_RINKEBY],
]);

const httpsUrls = new Map([
  [
    'mumbai',
    'https://polygon-mumbai.g.alchemy.com/v2/' +
      process.env.ALCHEMY_API_KEY_MUMBAI,
  ],
  [
    'rinkeby',
    'https://eth-rinkeby.alchemyapi.io/v2/' +
      process.env.ALCHEMY_API_KEY_RINKEBY,
  ],
]);

const ethersSupportedNetworkNames = new Map([
  ['mumbai', 'maticmum'],
  ['rinkeby', 'rinkeby'],
]);

const amount = new Map([
  ['mumbai', '1'],
  ['rinkeby', '0.1'],
]);

export {
  chainId,
  txUrl,
  apiKeys,
  httpsUrls,
  amount,
  ethersSupportedNetworkNames,
};
```

Comment: Do you have a failed transaction hash? Can you determine which line causes the problem? Can you try another provider? That error is quite generic, it could be the provider not working, the transaction reverting for some reason, etc.

Answer (score 0):

put2 more await on your codes sir

const balance = `await` web3.utils.fromWei(
await web3.eth.getBalance(constants['fromAddress']),
'ether'
);

const txHash = `await` ethers.utils.keccak256(signedTx);

does it work now?